# Angular directive pass data to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I hava a directive where i need to pass some data into the template.
In my understanding i should be able to do something like this.

```
return {
 template: '<p>{{answers}}</p>',
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
   data: '='
},

scope.answers = scope.data.answers;
```

my scope.answers = ["no", "yes", "Yes", "Yes"]

But no data is show in the html. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: What is the question?  Does this not work? What does your HTML using this directive look like?

Comment: and for that matter, where is this `scope.answers = scope.data.answers;` at in the code?  it certainly isn't part of the directive definition.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work. scope.data should come from parent controller.

**In View:**

```
<my-directive data ="myData"></my-directive>
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.myData = {
answers: ["no", "yes", "Yes", "Yes"]
};
```

**In directive template:**

```
<p ng-repeat="answer in answers">{{answer}}</p>
```

Comment: This is what comes from my controller 
    $scope.chartData = {
        title: question.title,
        answers: resp.data.answers,
        totalAnswers: resp.data.totalSurveySubmits
      }

But it still does not produce any results in html

Comment: Do this in you view:

<my-directive data ="chartData"></my-directive>

Also, in template of your directive use <p ng-repeat = "answer in answers">{{answer}}</p>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the post of @Devanshu Madan, I'd like to share a link to a tutorial. Creating a directive to pass data into, and render in the template section of the specific directive can be easily achieved following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters) tutorial.

Better to have a look at the link, with proper information you'll get the needed background information.